# How to use VLOOKUP with two sheets where the rows don't correspond?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Currently, I have two sheets of data. One is data I have and the other is a master list of data.

I'm trying to see if A1,B1 in myData sheet matches some An,Bn in the masterData and if it is say "correct" or "incorrect if it is not next to the data in myData

So below I would want column C to say correct for the first and third rows and incorrect in the second row

```
  myData
  A      B
Z0 Z1   Dog
Z0 Z5   Cat
Z0 Z6   Horse

  masterData
  A      B
Z0 Z1   Dog
Z0 Z2   Bird
Z0 Z3   Fish
Z0 Z4   Turtle
Z0 Z5   Lion
Z0 Z6   Horse
```

This is what I'm trying so far but I'm getting a "The formula you typed contains an error", error. Even if I wasn't getting an error I don't think it would be right because I think it would look for if A1 is some An and B1 is Bm

```
   =IF((NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, masterData!A:A, 1, FALSE)))) AND (NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, masterData!B:B,2, FALSE)))),correct, incorrect)
```

So if A2 of myData is in column A of masterData and B2 is in column B of masterData say correct else incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(B1=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),"Correct","Incorrect")
```

Comment: @ Scott Craner Thanks, Scott! I didn't catch that.